# I can't load yolov7 model

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov7

I'm a python beginner and after research about yolov7 load model. I can't find anyways that able to load yolov7 models to my code. I may do it wrong at some parts, so I'm here seek for helps. Hopefully someone can help me figure out how to load a pretrained yolov7  models. I also try to do someway but I think i do it wrong or it not work with me. I hope that someone can help me find a way to load yolov7 model (.pt file), and it able to run / i understand it.

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible example code that you have problems to get to run?

Comment: i had try torch hub and torch load but I'm not sure at some parts and it not work for me. I also tried using YOLO library of ultralytics but it not  work for  me too. Sr for late i'm not online this forum in a longtimes